# Why sometimes 'ing' form is not used?

Tags: complementation, verbs-of-perception

I often encounter statments where "ing" form isn't used. I wonder if "ing" form is incorrect in that context. For Example:

> Watch me play.(i.e Piano)

instead of

> Watch me playing.

I see it usually but couldn't understand what's the difference between them or if anyone is wrong. 
More examples

> You are going to hear me roar.
>
> I grew up watch his movies...
>
> I saw birds do these kind of things on hill.

Comment: "I grew up watch his movies" is not correct. That's one case where you *should* use the -ing form. (Correct version: "I grew up watching his movies.")

Answer (score 6):

Verbs of perception like *see, hear, watch, feel* take both *-ing*-form and bare infinitival<sup>†</sup> clauses as complements, but there is a slight difference of *aspect* between them:

- The infinitival complement implies that what is perceived is a completed action.

  > He watched me play *means that he watched until I was finished playing*.
- The *-ing*-form complement implies that the action continues while it is perceived, but is not necessarily finished during that period.

  > He watched me playing *means that he watched for some time while I played, but implicates*<sup>‡</sup> *that he stopped some time before I finished*.

Your example *I grew up watch his movies*, however, is ungrammatical. *Grow up* is not a verb of perception and does not take bare infinitival complements. It takes *marked* infinitival complements, which describe an outcome of growing up, and subjectless *-ing*-form adjuncts, which describe actions and states of the person growing up during that period.

> I grew up to watch his movies *means that you watched his movies after you grew up—perhaps you knew him when you were a child but didn't realize he was a famous actor until later*.
>
> I grew up watching his movies *means that you watched his movies while you were growing up*.

---

<sup>†</sup> <sub>A *bare* infinitival clause is one headed by an infinitive which is not marked with *to*.</sub>

<sup>‡</sup> <sub>*Implicates* is a technical term for having a 'default' meaning which may in fact be contradicted.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I am no good at grammar and cannot tell you *why*. The words inside the parentheses are not necessary but are fine to use.

"I am playing (the) piano." This is what I am doing **now**.

"I play (the) piano." I know how to play the piano, but not playing it now. (Unless you are showing me and saying "Of course I play (the) piano."

> I grew up watch his movies..

That just doesn't sound right. "I grew up watching his movies." "I watch movies", means I watch movies in general. "I eat cake" -- same thing. I eat cake means I like cake and I will eat it. "I am eating cake", means I am doing this at this moment.

Your other examples all work.