# What does "I saw him wash the car" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

What does this sentence mean?

> I saw him wash the car

Does it mean "I saw him when he was washing the car"?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It doesn't *quite* mean "I saw him when he was washing the car".

As I have explained [elsewhere](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/115426/32)

> Verbs of perception like *see, hear, watch, feel* take both *-ing*-form and bare infinitival clauses as complements, but there is a slight difference of *aspect* between them:
>
> - The infinitival complement implies that what is perceived is a completed action.
>
>   > He watched me play *means that he watched until I was finished playing*.
> - The *-ing*-form complement implies that the action continues while it is perceived, but is not necessarily finished during that period.
>
>   > He watched me playing *means that he watched for some time while I played, but implicates that he stopped some time before I finished*.

So "I saw him wash the car" means that I saw him complete his action of washing the car, right down to finishing the job. "I saw him when he was washing the car" is a (very rough) paraphrase of *I saw him wash**ing** the car*.

Comment: As well as the *completed/ongoing* distinction in OP's example, there's also a possible distinction that's more likely in, say, *I thought about her going to work* (where using the continuous verb form also allows the possible meaning *...while **I** was going to work*). Not a particularly credible interpretation for OP's *exact* context, perhaps, but I think the syntax itself would allow that reading.

Comment: I think there might be a bit more to it. If person X accuses person Y of never washing the car, I would have no qualms with "But I saw person Y wash the car yesterday!" even if the speaker actually saw only part of the car-washing process.

Comment: @ruakh They might say that; but it would not be strictly accurate, and if the accusation was that Y had not *finished* washing the car it would not be responsive under the Gricean canons.

Comment: IME the distinction is mostly one of emphasis. I'd have no qualms about using the bare infinitive even for incomplete actions, if the *action* was what I perceived and wished to emphasize; "I heard him sing" does not, to me, necessarily imply that I stayed for the entire performance. OTOH, at least to my ear, using the gerund shifts the focus from the action to the subject; like you wrote in your answer, it's almost as if there was an implied "when he/she/it was" between the subject and the gerund, emphasizing the subject and marking the action as secondary. Of course, I'm no native speaker...

Comment: @IlmariKaronen singing/washing etc aren't gerunds in this context, they're participles. A gerund is adding the "ing" ending to turn a verb into a noun, as in "I'm afraid of flying". But (as a native speaker) I think I like your description of shifting the focus more than the one about whether the action was watched to completion. I see people wash cars all the time, even when I didn't see it from beginning to end.

Comment: @amalloy I think that particularly in this sort of context the distinction between gerund and participle is meaningless. *CGEL* calls the form *gerund-participle*, and understands *him washing the car* as a non-finite clause with a 'raised' subject, not an object pronoun modified by a participle phrase.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen It's true that the infinitive is not always strictly perfective: with atelic verbs it conveys a sense very little different (if at all) from that of the ger/ppl clause. But when a verb like *sing* or *wash* is used with an object it is usually 'recategorized' as telic. "I heard him sing three Schubert Lieder" implicates that you sat through all three of them.

Comment: "I saw him wash the car" usually implies that you only witnessed a portion of the act, although arguably, to "wash" something requires completion.  "I saw him washing the car" strongly implies that you only witnessed a portion of the act.  "I watched him wash the car" implies that you watched (perhaps intently) until completion.

Answer (score 20):

It could mean a couple different things, depending on emphasis and context. You've listed one possible meaning:

> I saw him when he was washing the car.

By including *when* in this version, this particular sentence seems to emphasis time. In other words:
"When did you see him?"
"I saw him when he was washing the car."

Another possible meaning:

> I saw that he washed the car.

This version emphasizes that you know he washed the car because you witnessed the event:
"The car looks dirty – are you sure he washed it?"
"Yes, I saw that he washed the car."

Or, perhaps we want to emphasize who washed the car:

> I saw that it was him (and not someone else) who washed the car.

"Somebody washed my car – I wonder of it was Deborah."
"No I saw that it was him (and not Deborah) who washed the car.

---

When you take a simple sentence like yours, and ask what it means, it's hard to say precisely what it means without surrounding context. The gist of the original sentence is simple:

- He washed the car
- You saw him do it

but any other meaning is conveyed more by the situation and the surrounding conversation than it is by the individual words themselves.

Comment: I would be careful with the translation "I saw that he washed the car", since I might say *that* if I were looking at the car wash's logs, and didn't see him wash the car. And I would agree with StoneyB that completion is usually strongly implied by "I saw him wash the car". That said, you bring up a good point that it could be used to emphasize who washed the car.

Comment: I completely disagree that it implies completion, as do many other people on that answer

Answer (score 0):

You're overcomplicating things. It simply means that he was seen as he was washing the car and it doesn't mean that the act was completed. It only takes a split second of observing this action to be able to make that statement