# Can you explain about the constructions of the type "verb+noun+another verb"?

Tags: difference, understanding

I have seen constructions like:

> The number of electrons present inside the metal is large.

In the given case, the noun **electrons** is directly followed by the verb **present**.

It could also be written using as adjective phrase as:

> The number of electrons **which are** present inside the metal is large.

In this case, now noun **electrons** and verb **present** are separated by an adjective phrase.

Now consider,

> I saw them destroy you.
>
> She helped him find a buyer.

In these cases, I believe the noun/pronoun and the verb cannot by separated by any phrase like in the first example. I feel these constructions are a bit odd because of lack of an auxiliary verb and also due to the consecutive use of two different verbs with of course one noun/pronoun in between them. Can these have alternatives like that for the first example? Which these types of constructions are called (as)?

Comment: *Present* is not a verb in your first example but an adjective, precisely as it is in the paraphrase with a relative clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We refer this to as a "complex catenative construction." (I know it sounds fancy, but there's nothing odd with such constructions.)

A complex catenative construction has an intervening noun phrase,* which is the direct object, followed by a subordinate clause functioning as a catenative complement.

Catenative verbs admit various kinds of catenative complements, realized by non-finite clauses<sup>†</sup>, depending on the verb in the main clause.

The verb "saw" is a verb of perception, that is, a verb that conveys the experience of one of the physical senses.
This verb allows a bare infinitive as a complement.<sup>‡</sup>

"Help" is a special verb  in that it licenses either a to-infinitive or a bare infinitive as a complement; the latter, however, is more common in modern English.

---

<sup>*</sup><sub>A simple catenative construction does not have an intervening noun phrase (e.g., *I forgot to do that*).</sub>

<sup>†</sup> <sub>There's a brief discussion about non-finite clauses [here](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/grammar/nonfiniteclauses.html).</sub>

<sup>‡</sup><sub>A gerund is also allowed. See [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/123901/what-does-i-saw-him-wash-the-car-mean/123903#123903).</sub>

Comment: **I stood amazed.** Is it the same kind of construction?

Comment: @AnubhavSingh Yeah, they are the same 'catenative construction'.

Answer (score 1):

Consider "I saw **they who** destroy you" or "She helped **he who** found a buyer."

Comment: Is it correct usage?

Comment: Yes. For example "I help those who help themselves".